# How to POST HTML form data to .json file using $http.post() method using angular js and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am working on creating an embedded javascript application. For testing purposes, I want to create a input box in HTML and when the user enters their name in the box, a page should come up displaying what the user entered. further i want to post the name the user entered in a json file using $http.post() method. We have an embedded server which handles the POST request. But I am not able to post anything to the json file?

This is my HTML file:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Client-Side Application Framework -- UserDetails</title>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.3.5/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form ng-submit="sendPost()">
    <input ng-model="newName"/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<p> Hello {{config.newName}} </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript file

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
    var configUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +"/ext/hp/userdetails/cp/app-config.json";
     var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: $scope.newName
            })
        });
    $http.post(configUrl,data).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.config = data;
        })
    };                   
})
```

I need to post the data to app-config.json file and then retrieve the data I posted and display it in the browser.

I have an empty app-config.json file.

Comment: please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include snippets and what you've tried

Comment: You need to show us some code, and what you have done so far...

Comment: I will add code in sometime :) Thanks for replying :)

Comment: @Lotus91 Added HTML and JS code snippets

Comment: Does your JSON file stay empty even if you hard code the data? Like;  $scope.config= {name: "Hello"}; and  $scope.newName = ""; before your sendPost function ?

Comment: @Lotus91 Yes. I tried hardcoding the data like $scope.config = "sometext". Still no change.